# Subtract time using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, bi-publisher

I'm creating a report using BI Publisher. Now, I want is to subtract 4 hours in the date. For example, the date I get in the oracle database is below,

`2019-09-23T10:09:34.054+00:00`

Now I want it to return in report using sql is,

`2019-09-23T06:09:34.054+00:00`

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INTERVAL`?

```
SELECT ts - INTERVAL '4' HOUR
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

If your source data is actually text, and not a bona fide timestamp column, then you may use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` to first do a conversion:

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE(s, 'T', ' ') 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') AS ts_original,
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE(s, 'T', ' ') 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') - INTERVAL '4' HOUR AS ts_offset
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to subtract a fraction of time.  Like this for 4 hours ago:

```
select sysdate-1/6 from dual;
```